# Pushing many objects in my array erases all previous objects of the array (React with Hooks)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I want to push an object in my array, at every loop of a forEach,
But at every loop, it seems that my array becomes empty, so my array only have  the last object pushed in,

It looks like this line from my code doesn't work :

```
setSeriesLikedDetails([...seriesLikedDetails, dataSerieDetail.data]);
```

because when I do the

```
console.log("seriesLikedDetails ", seriesLikedDetails);
```

instead of having an array of objects, I always have 1 object in the array (the last one pushed in)..

Here's a part of the code of the component :

```
function Likes(props) {
  const [moviesLiked, setMoviesLiked] = useState([]);
  const [seriesLiked, setSeriesLiked] = useState([]);
  const [moviesLikedDetails, setMoviesLikedDetails] = useState([]);
  const [seriesLikedDetails, setSeriesLikedDetails] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadMoviesLikedDetails();
    loadSeriesLikedDetails();
  }, [moviesLiked, seriesLiked]);

  async function loadMoviesLikedDetails() {
    setMoviesLikedDetails([]);
    moviesLiked.forEach(async movie => {
      try {
        const dataMovieDetail = await axios.get(
          `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movie}?api_key=381e8c936f62f2ab614e9f29cad6630f&language=fr`
        );
        console.log("MovieDetail ", dataMovieDetail.data);
        setMoviesLikedDetails(movieDetails => [
          ...movieDetails,
          dataMovieDetail.data
        ]);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    });
  }

  async function loadSeriesLikedDetails() {
    setSeriesLikedDetails([]);
    seriesLiked.forEach(async serie => {
      try {
        const dataSerieDetail = await axios.get(
          `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/${serie}?api_key=381e8c936f62f2ab614e9f29cad6630f&language=fr`
        );
        console.log("SerieDetail ", dataSerieDetail.data);
        setSeriesLikedDetails(serieDetails => [
          ...serieDetails,
          dataSerieDetail.data
        ]);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is most likely because in the forEach callback the seriesLikedDetails is allways the same reference whereas setSeriesLikedDetails changes the actual array you want to track.

So when your on the last iteration of the forEach you just add the last value to the initial array and set it as the current array.

By doing this way instead:

```
async function loadSeriesLikedDetails() {
    const newArray = [...seriesLikedDetails];
    const promises = seriesLiked.map(async serie => {
      try {
        const dataSerieDetail = await axios.get(
          `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/${serie}?api_key=381e8c936f62f2ab614e9f29cad6630f&language=fr`
        );
        console.log("SerieDetail ", dataSerieDetail.data);

        newArray.push(dataSerieDetail.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    });
    Promise.all(promises).then(()=>setSeriesLikedDetails(newArray));

  }
```

You will update the state once with the correct new value.

Comment: perfect, it works now with your edited answer ! Thanks

Comment: Even if it does not explain you initial problem, FrankerZ's answer below is more suited to your need.

Comment: ok np, can you let your answer because I got an issue with the other answer :D

Answer (score 1):

`seriesLikedDetails` is being cached here, and is only updating when the component rerenders. Because `loadSeriesLikedDetails()` isn't called a second time during the rerenders, your initial `seriesLikedDetails` remains an empty array.

Let's go over what happens internally (Your code):

- Component gets rendered. `useEffect()`'s get fired, and run.
- Axios calls are being made, and then a call to `setSeriesLikedDetails()` is made. `seriesLikedDetails` now contains one element.
- Component is now rerendered. When component is rerendered, `loadSeriesLikedDetails();` is **NOT** called as `seriesLiked` hasn't changed.
- Axios calls are continued to be made (Called from the original render), but the current value of `seriesLikedDetails` remains an empty array, because this is still happening in the original render.

Avoid using `Promise.all` here as you may want to do sequential updates to your UI as updates come in. In this case, you can use `setSeriesLikedDetails` with a function, to always pull the current value to update it:

```
function Likes(props) {
  const [moviesLiked, setMoviesLiked] = useState([]);
  const [seriesLiked, setSeriesLiked] = useState([]);
  const [moviesLikedDetails, setMoviesLikedDetails] = useState([]);
  const [seriesLikedDetails, setSeriesLikedDetails] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadSeriesLikedDetails();
  }, [seriesLiked]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("seriesLikedDetails ", seriesLikedDetails);
  }, [seriesLikedDetails]);

  async function loadSeriesLikedDetails() {
    seriesLiked.forEach(async serie => {
      try {
        const dataSerieDetail = await axios.get(
          `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/${serie}?api_key=381e8c936f62f2ab614e9f29cad6630f&language=fr`
        );
        console.log("SerieDetail ", dataSerieDetail.data);
        setSeriesLikedDetails(currSeriesDetails => [...currSeriesDetails, dataSerieDetail.data]);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    });
  }
```

It's as simple as passing a function:

```
setSeriesLikedDetails(currSeriesDetails => [...currSeriesDetails, dataSerieDetail.data]);
```

In addition, you may also wish to reset the array at the start (Or write it so you only fetch the movies/series you haven't fetched already):

```
async function loadSeriesLikedDetails() {
     setMoviesLikedDetails([]); // Reset array
```

See [Functional Updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) apart of the docs.

Comment: My answer deals and explains the scoping issue the OP had but this should be how to do it.

Comment: hello, I tried your answer, it works perfectly for tv shows but for movies it looks like the forEach is done 2 times per item in moviesLiked hmm (because in fact I have to do this for movies AND tv shows)

I have 3 items in moviesLiked, but the forEach is done 6 times instead of 3 (2x per items)
setMoviesLikedDetails(currDetails => [...currDetails, dataMovieDetail.data]);

Comment: Post your updated code. Also, try using `currMovieDetails` to avoid name overlaps.

Comment: @Versifiction See my updated answer. Since @remix32's code uses `Promise.all()` and updates everything afterwards, it will overwrite any details that may exist. You likely want to reset your array at the start of the `loadSeriesLikedDetails()`.

Comment: I posted the updated code, it's just the same thing about series that I copied for movies.

So in the render, I map on moviesLikeDetails and I got every movie in double

Comment: See what I said about resetting the array at the beginning of the loop

Comment: I did what you said, but the duplication of the movies is still there, and it's weird because for the series everything works fine, I keep looking for the mistake

Comment: I don't see you resetting your array in the code you posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201159/discussion-between-versifiction-and-frankerz).